# Typescript - Accessing array of objects inside Array of Objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two objects in an array.
I am looping through objects, how do I access detail_feedback object array inside a particular object (Object 1)?

```
  [{name:'myname',
        detail_feedback :[{question:'Qn1',answer:'Ans1'},{question:'Qn2',answer:'Ans2'},{question:'Qn3',answer:'Ans3'}]},
    {name:'yourname',
        detail_feedback :[{question:'Qn1',answer:'Ans1'},{question:'Qn2',answer:'Ans2'},{question:'Qn3',answer:'Ans3'}]},    
        ]
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated..!
Thanks

Comment: `obj.detail_feedback` should work. Once you have a reference to the current object in the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work..!

Comment: If that didn't work is because you have some other problem, can you share some of your code?

Comment: `myArray[0].detail_feedback`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
// import your json obj
import data from 'yourjson.json'

// iterate over the elements of the array
data.forEach(obj => {
  // access 'detail_feedback' prop of each object
  console.log(obj['detail_feedback'])
})
```

Comment: Didnt help !!....also tried -->  for (let i = 0; i < this.myarray.length; i++) {
      console.log('i=>'+this.myarray[i]['detail_feedback'])} ...NO LUCK..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the array by index:

```
arr[0].detail_feedback
```

will return the detail_feedback at the index you want. If you want to loop over it and extract all feedbacks use:

```
const feedbacks = arr.map(item => item.detail_feedback)
```

Answer (score 0):

first, get the first level and then iteratate on the childrens

```js
const data =  [{name:'myname',
        detail_feedback :[{question:'Qn1',answer:'Ans1'},{question:'Qn2',answer:'Ans2'},{question:'Qn3',answer:'Ans3'}]},
    {name:'yourname',
        detail_feedback :[{question:'Qn1',answer:'Ans1'},{question:'Qn2',answer:'Ans2'},{question:'Qn3',answer:'Ans3'}]},    
        ]
data.forEach( (element) => {
    element.detail_feedback = element.detail_feedback;
    console.log(element.detail_feedback)
   
    element.detail_feedback.forEach(item=>{
    item.question
    console.log(item.question, item.answer)
    })
    
});
```